# UICollectionView with 2 columns squash the second column

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionview` that's embedded in a `UIView` (I know it raises questions as per why - long story short, it's the easiest way I can accomplish this UI).

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to center the 2 columns with right in the middle with a little bit of padding from the left and right side between the cells (the purple blocks are images, just had to blur them out because it's a client).

I tried so many options and just cant seem to figure it out. It always squishes the right cells with the images. This is what i have so far:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    let layout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 10, right: 5)
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
}

extension LobbyViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        return CGSize(width: ((width / 2)), height: 150)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Here's the effect:

[image: preview]

Comment: Put a break point at `return CGSize(width: ((width / 2)), height: 150)` and check if its calling.

Comment: @Dharmesh yes, it's calling it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem

```
CGSize(width: ((width / 2)), height: 150)
```

You also need to consider section inset's left, right and cell spacing of collection view.

for ex:

```
CGSize(width: ((width - 10 - minimumInteritemSpacing) / 2), height: 150)
```

you can get `minimumInteritemSpacing` from `collectionView.collectionViewLayout` property

I have set 10 static here, because of this.

```
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 10, right: 5)
```

Comment: And how do I get the minimumInteritemSpacing (it's set to 0)? 
If i do return  `CGSize(width: ((width - 10 ) / 2), height: 150)` still get a lot of spacing between + the squished effect

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

Try with `return CGSize(width: ((collectionView.frame.widht / 2)), height: 150)`

and change `MinSpacing` to `0`

[image]

This will remove space between `collectionviewcell`.

may be this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

- Give padding from all sides of collection view as you required for design and then write this code in your view controller :

  ```
  let numberOfCellsPerRow: CGFloat = 2
  if let flowLayout = yourCollectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
      flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 160, height: 160)
  }
  ```

Hope it will help you!!